# Mocking a Python object without method calls

Tags: python, python-mock, pytest-mock

Imagine a class like so:

```
class Foo():

    def method_1(self):
        bar = Bar()
        bazz = Bazz(bar)
        return bazz.method_2()
```

For unit testing, how can we mock the `Bar` object when we never call any methods on it, we're just passing it as a parameter to the `Bazz` constructor? (Yes, this is not ideal, but this pattern can be found in a top-level class wiring together different objects via dependency injection).

Comment: You can just mock it as usual, e.g. something like `@mock.patch("foo.Bar")` (provided you import it like `from bar import Bar`). Maybe I don't understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

You do call the `Bar` object, when you execute: `bar = Bar()`, so you can easily mock it:

```
mock_bar = mocker.MagicMock(name='Bar')
mocker.patch('foo.Bar', new=mock_bar)
# mock_foo.return_value = the new mocked object
```